# how to prevent insertion of certain offensive words in codeigniter using a database

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, input

I'm developing a website using codeigniter that allows users to post free ads and search for ads, I'm looking for a fast way to check the user input against a list of offensive words stored in database table, so that if a user enters a bad word, one from those listed in that table then it should be removed (not entered). my table is using the MySql fulltext search feature.

I tried using the like in sql but I was told that it gets slow when the records reach thousands.

is there any suitable solution in codeigniter ?

Comment: Are you doing that check before the user posts an ad?

Comment: I think yes, this process would be done before insertion, unless doing it after insertion is favored somehow.

Comment: rcdmk .... if you open your eyes well you'll know what have I tried.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this. In your situation I wouldn't even use SQL, I would just write a config option in CI with a regex for all the bad words, and then match your input against those bad words. E.g.

```
$config['bad_words'] = "/[\s](ass|sex|butt|badword)[\s]/i";
$input               = preg_replace($config['bad_words'],"",$input);
```

This would work if you have thousands of records, but might be a little slow with thousands of bad words. Of course, regex is a bad idea if you have more than a few bad words you want to use. If you have thousands of bad words I would just use the "like" in mysql. It does get a little slow, but the impact on performance not that big.

With SQL, I would create a database of bad words (or bad word regex-es). Each row of the bad_words table would then have a regex to match a bad word, such as "fu.k". When validating input to filter bad words out, you would then need to:

```
<?php 
  $res = mysql_query( "select * from bad_words" );
  ...
  //get all rows in array $badWords
  ...
  $myRegexMatch = implode ( "|" , $badWords );
  preg_replace($myRegexMatch,"",$input);
?>
```

This is probably one of the fastest solutions out there, it's easy to implement and it's pretty quick. If you want to make it faster you can even cache the regex fetched from the database, using database caching.

If you're interested in doing it even faster (which you really shouldn't need), I would write a database trigger/constraint that does this regex match within the database whenever an "ad" is supposed to be inserted.

Comment: Thank you very much for response !

the benefit of using SQL is that we can always update those words or add new ones easily, simply by inserting new records to the table of banned words, it's easier and more flexible than modifying the regualr expression I geuss.

what about using fulltext search in that process, is it good? when a user inserts the ad we enter it any way and then after it gets into the db we can search it for bad words using the Fulltext feature in MySql. what do you think ?

Comment: Of course, I'd use SQL over regex anytime, provided the site is big enough. I'll edit my answer to better suit the question in a short while; Fulltext search is actually a pretty good solution but you wouldn't want to do an sql fulltext search on every display - the filtering should be done before insertion. There may be a quicker solution by constructing a dynamic Regex from the database table of bad words and then filtering the ad before insertion. I'll get back to you shortly.

Comment: I've updated my answer with the fastest solution I could come up with, without doing significant research. Hope you like it ;)